# how would you say it in words?

Tags: java

The following code, how would you say in words?

```
AudioInputStream cutStream = new AudioInputStream(
new FileInputStream(inFile), audioFormat, sourceDataLine.getLongFramePosition());
```

Answer (score 6):

Create a new audio input stream using  the specified  file, format and position.

Answer (score 3):

Cutstream is a new AudioInputStream.  I passed into the constructor inFile, audioFormat, and the longFramePosition from sourceDataLine.

Comment: +1 I love the reflective nature of this: *I passed...*

Answer (score 2):

Instantiate a new instance of the AudioStream class, with a new instance of a FileInputStream reading from infile, using the local object audioformat, and the object returned by the getLongFramePosition method of the local object sourceDataLine and store the instance in the local variable cutStream.

Comment: Thank you Ziplin , your explanation helped me undestand the code statement

Comment: @Carlos - please accept this answer if it was the one that helped understanding the code (just click on the checkmark next to the question)

Comment: Yes, please do carlos :)

Answer (score 1):

"Create a new AudioInputStream from some parameters configured elsewhere."

I think what you may really be looking for is the [Javadoc for AudioInputStream's constructor](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#AudioInputStream(java.io.InputStream,%20javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat,%20long)).

Answer (score 1):

*"Create a new instance of AudioInputStream, giving it a FileInputStream to the input file, the audioformat and sourceDataLine dot getLongFramePosition."*